# iOS which of my 15 (!) Certificates is obsolete?

Tags: ios, certificate, ios-provisioning

In Keychain Assistant I have *fifteen* different Certificates. I am trying to correlate them with those that show up in the Developer Portal (in either of my two separate accounts). That takes care of some -- essentially those that show up with a gray disclosure triangle to the left side. But there are some Certificates, without the triangle, that seem more "global" and which do not have counterparts in Dev Portal. They have outlandish expiration dates, like Feb 2027.

Of course I do not recall requesting or creating these... it's been 7 years of iOS development, and I was not as compulsive about taking notes. So my question (finally, here it is): which of these are still being used? I am not about to go randomly deleting them, but the cloud of unknowing is frustrating. I suspect some are just deadwood.

To repeat (forestalling some impulsive replies) I know what all the app-specific dev, distribution, push, etc. Certificates are for. Following are the (apparent) orphans, that may have some overarching global role:

Apple Application Integration Certification Authority - July 2017

Apple iPhone Certification Authority - Apr 2022

Apple iPhone OS Provisioning Profile Signing - May 2020

Apple Root Certification Authority - Feb 2025

Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority - Feb 2016

Developer ID Certification Authority - Feb 2027

Answer (score 0):

At least for : May 2020 Apple Root Certification Authority

I think it's related to MDM, did you ever configure APNS on a MDM system ? It could be it.
I found [this doc](http://cookbooks.ca.com/camdm/2014/05/16/how-to-obtain-an-apns-certificate-part-1-of-3/) mentionning it and I remember something like that a long time ago for air-watch configuration.

Comment: I can attest that two of the aforelisted certificates are still necessary. I ran this at the command line: `codesign -vv -d MyApp.app`. What I got included `Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority` and `Authority=Apple Root CA`.

Those correspond very clearly to the fourth and fifth Certificates in my list.